# JBoss Init Script - Trapping issue

Tags: bash, jboss, jboss7.x, init.d, shell-trap

I have a script that I'm making to use to start/stop/etc a JBoss AS (v7.1.1). I'm running on SUSE Enterprise 11, so the provided initscript doesn't work. The problem I'm running into with my script is that the cleanup function is never called.

```
#!/bin/sh

HOME="/var/rulesserver"
CURRENT=$HOME/logs/current
LOGFILE=$HOME/logs/`date -u +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S`.log
COMMAND=/usr/local/jboss/bin/standalone.sh
SELF=/usr/sbin/jboss-as-standalone

function cleanup() {
    rm $CURRENT
}

function run() {
    trap cleanup 1 2 3 6 15
    nohup $COMMAND &> $CURRENT
}

case $1 in
    "start" )
        echo "Starting the server..."
        if [ -e $CURRENT ]
        then
            echo "ERROR: The server is already running"
        else
            ln -s $LOGFILE $CURRENT
            run &
            echo "Server started"
        fi
        ;;
    "stop" )
        echo "Stopping the server..."
        killall java
        echo "Server stopped"
        ;;
    "status" )
        if [ -e $CURRENT ]
        then
            echo "The server is currently running"
        else
            echo "The server is currently stopped"
        fi
        ;;
    "cleanup" )
        cleanup
        ;;
    "restart" )
        $SELF stop
        $SELF start
        ;;
    * )
        $SELF start
        ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be confused, but can you not just do

```
function run() {
    ( nohup $COMMAND ; rm $CURRENT )
}
```

?

$COMMAND would block till i dies and then there would be an rm and then the subshell would exit? There would be no need for trap.

Comment: I didn't know that would work. I was afraid that the second command would never be run if the first was killed.

Answer (score 2):

There is a method provided in the standalone.sh startup script that you can use to control it's behavior. Just set the value of environment variable LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND to some value, ie.

```
LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND=true
```

before calling the script and then you will no longer need nohup to do the job for you, and no cleanup will be necessary.

Also, there is an option to tell JBoss AS to write the "console output" to a file, so you can still have the messages that it will be generating.

One more thing: I personally do not think that `killall java` is 100% clever thing to do in all the possible circumstances.

Comment: I would agree that `killall java` is fairly dangerous. I installed Java on the server for JBoss, so I was pretty sure there wasn't anything else using Java on the computer.